# If I disable the IOBs in my custom IP, will it still work? What are the IOBs for anyway?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I'm designing an ethernet mac controller which exceeded the number of IOBs in the Spartan 3E starter kit. I'm planning to disable the IOBs.. Will it still work? What are the IOBs for anyway?

Comment: What do you mean disable IOBs? If you are not using all the IOs, you should connect them to their default values, or leave the outputs to float. If you designing and IP and need to test it, then you should use Vivado and viarual IOs. Alternative, create a wrapper around your IP and use the wrapper to synthesize and P&R your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will almost certainly not work if you don't have enough IOBs.  IOB = Input/Output Block.  It is a block of logic that resides near each pin inside of Xilinx FPGAs.  The tools are telling you that you don't have enough pins to accomplish what you need to do.  You should create a pinout of your FPGA and map it to the pins on your mac controller.  That information is assigned in the UCF (User Constraints File).  If you don't have enough pins, you will need to either get a new custom IP that is less resource hungry or get a bigger FPGA.